# I need to create a row with col-8 and col-4 which collapses at a small size, but my paragraph won't change size when the webpage decreases

Tags: html, css, image, row, col

I need to create a row with col-8 and col-4 which collapses at a small size, but my paragraph won't change size when the webpage changes size. I'm not sure what in my css or html is making this happen?

[What paragraph and image look like at large size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Aa2D.jpg)

[What paragraph and image look like at small size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0w1A.png)

[my css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmVcJ.png)

[my html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6yVe.png)

Comment: Welcome! To attract better and more answers it is best to include the code you're having a question about and not just a link to a screenshot. The best way to do this is delete everything not related to your problem until you have a short example that helps others to recreate the problem. I strongly suggest you read about [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify a col size, such as col-sm-4 col-sm-8.

There are 4 column sized, xs, sm, md, lg.

Also that -220 margin on your paragraph can be what is causing the problem.

Update:
Also just noticed you have a container and a nested container fluid. You do not want to nest containers. Just one container is enough.

Are you using bootstrap? If so, make sure to reference the cdn in the in the html or download it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use width in your CSS for the paragraph. Because this is conflicting with bootstrap col-md-* width

Answer (score -1):

One of your property might be overriding the previous one.For such problems,you can either try to arrange them in required preference or just use !important in front of desired property